# Ring theory questions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I was doing exercises of algebra and I’m struggling with this exercise. I have to say if the propositions are true or false, demonstrate it if it is true and give a counterexample if it is false. Here are the questions.

> Let $P \in \mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ be an irreducible polynomial. The quotient ring $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/\langle P\rangle$ is a field.

I think I can consider $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ as $\mathbb{C}[X][Y]$ and then do the usual proof. So I would say this is true.

> Let $I$ be a proper ideal of a commutative ring $A$. If all the elements of $A / I $ are invertible then $I$ is a maximal ideal of $A$.

I know that $I$ is maximal iff $A/ I$ is a field.  So I would say this is false since $\overline0_A \in A / I $ is invertible thus $A / I $ cannot be a field.

> In a commutative ring $A$, the product of two divisors of zero is a divisor of zero.

The definition we have if this: $a\in A \setminus \{0_A\}$ is a divisor of zero if $\exists b\in A \setminus\{0_A\}$ such that $ab=0_A$. I would say that this is true

Correct me if I did mistakes thank you!

Comment: Your first sentence is false, isn't it?  With $P(x,y)=x$, this is irreducible, yet $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle x \rangle \cong \mathbb{C}[y]$ is not a field, right?  Or am I wrong?

Comment: Also, you can't do the "usual demonstration" with $\mathbb{C}[x,y] \cong \mathbb{C}[x][y]$.  The theorem you want is for polynomials in $F[y]$ where $F$ is a field, but $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is not a field.

Comment: (1) Please use informative titles. "Ring theory question" is too general to be useful. (2) Please use appropriate tags. You are asking about ring theory, and you didn't think to add the [ring-theory] tag? That will prevent users who follow the tag from seeing it highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

1. The polynomial $X\in\Bbb{C}[X,Y]$ is irreducible, but $\Bbb{C}[X,Y]/(X)$ is not a field.
2. The quotient $A/I$ is not the same as the complement $A\backslash I$.
3. Do you think that it is false or true? You write both. Anyway, note that if $a$ is a zero divisor then **there exists** some nonzero $b$ such that $ab=0$. It is not true that $ab=0$ **for all** $b\in A$. So your argument does not hold.

Comment: Yes, i will edit those. For the 3rd. If take two divisor of zero $a$ and $c$. Then there exists some non zero b and d such that $ab=0$ and $cd=0$. Then if i consider the product $ab$ and if this a divisor of zero then there exists $e$ non zero such that $ac*e=0$ where e is in $A$ and non zero so i can take $e=b*d$ since $b$ and $d$ are in $A$ and non zero. Finally we have $acbd=abcd=0$ because $A$ is commutative. Then it is true

Comment: What if $bd=0$, though?

Comment: If $bd=0$then i cannot consider them by definition but i'm not sure if this means that $ac$ is not a divisor of zero.

Comment: Hint:  why not just consider $abc$?

Comment: If $b$ is a zero divisor then $bd=0$ for some nonzero $d$. Then surely $(ab)d=0$ for any $a$.

Comment: If i understand right this means that in particular if $a$ is a divisor of zero we have $(ab)d=0$ for some non zero $d$, then the proposition is true.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1.** If a polynomial $P$ in the ring $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is irreducible, then $\langle P\rangle$ is a maximal ideal. This follows from the fact that every ideal in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is principal (instead of $\mathbb{C}$ you can have any field). The statement is no longer valid in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$, which is *not* a principal ideal domain. Consider $\langle X\rangle\subsetneq\langle X,Y\rangle\subsetneq\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$.

The ideal generated by an irreducible polynomial is maximal in the set of proper principal ideals (the proof of the single variable case carries over), but not in the set of all proper ideals. Actually, *no* irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ generates a maximal ideal.

**Question 2.** Is a ring $R$ in which *every* element is invertible a field? Also $0$ should be invertible, so…

**Question 3.** Let $a$ be a zero-divisor, so $a\ne0$ and $ab=0$ for some $b\ne0$. Then also $b$ is a zero-divisor, isn't it? But is the product $ab$ a zero-divisor?

Comment: I think i understood the first two. For the 3rd $ab$ is not a zero divisor because we would need that $ ab \neq 0 \forall a \in A, b\in A$ or we know that there exists some non zero $b$ such that $ab=0$. So $ab$ is not a zero-divisor.

Comment: @vadkoslov $ab=0$ by assumption, so it is not a zero-divisor, according to your definition.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.